# Why do we generally add capacitors in series with AC sources when DC also exists in the circuit?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, circuit-protection, bias, function-generator

This is probably a noob question but, essentially, why do we often place capacitors in series with AC signal sources? I understand that we sometimes want to isolate the DC signal to "its own" circuit but is there any other reason why we do this, such as to protect a function generator from a high DC voltage?

Would there, for instance, be something wrong with the following circuit:

[image: Circuit with ac and dc but no capacitor]

Comment: Your question is ambiguous as worded. I believe you mean to ask "in series with AC sources", not in front of. In "front of" doesn't mean anything. You may edit the question.

Comment: The circuit is neither wrong nor right - what makes it wrong or right is the intention behind designing that circuit. If you intended it to be an amplifier, clearly it's wrong; if you intended it to add a little dc bias to an AC signal then it *could be* correct. But nobody can say a circuit is correct or otherwise without some idea of the aim of the designer.

Comment: Placing a capacitor in a circuit to "protect a function generator from a high DC voltage"  (or some other components) is called a "blocking capacitor".  Nearly every tube amp uses blocking caps to separate amplifier stages.   In this schematic, the two ".02 600" capacitors do this. 
  https://robrobinette.com/images/Guitar/HowAmpsWork/5F1_Schematic.gif

Answer (score 2):

We don't *normally* place capacitors in front of AC sources.

What you are calling an AC source in your question is actually an "AC *signal* source", (as opposed to an AC power source). In that case, we might place what is called a DC-blocking capacitor in series with the AC source which allows the AC source to "ride on top of" or superimpose itself onto the DC-bias. Along with a resistor in series with the DC source, it protects the sources from each other, and prevents the sources from fighting each other where both sources meet which allows both to appear together on the line. Without them, it would be unstoppable force vs immovable object for ideal sources.

In your example, a resistor in series with the AC source present a voltage drop which distorts the voltage signal which you do not need to live with because a properly chosen capacitor won't do this.

Why do we use a resistor in series with the DC source and not an inductor (for AC-blocking)? Because if you try and use the capacitors and inductor together they will have resonance effects. Real inductors also do not approach the ideal as closely as resistors or capacitors so we try to use capacitors over inductors whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So just to calarify, there is atleast nothing which prevents us (such as the sources affecting eachother) from, e.g. putting an AC signal source and DC voltage source in parallell without capacitors if that's the kind of circuit we want? I didn't quite get what you meant by the sources "fighting each other where both sources meet ".

Comment: @Gabriel_Shafiq_A There is something preventing you and it's the part you quoted. Remember that an ideal voltage source tries to keep the voltage across its terminals at some fixed value, no matter what. Imagine what happens when you connect two ideal sources across the same two nodes so that they both want different voltages across those node. Which one wins? The AC source? or the DC source? Or do they source or sink as much current as they can to force that node to the voltage they want until one of the sources explodes?

Comment: Ok that was actually a very good explaination of a fundamental concept. A lot more about electronics is making sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel_Shafiq_A You design a stage of an amplifier. To do that you need to set the DC operating point -- also called the quiescent operating point. If you then hooked up a low-impedance AC source to it, you'd mess up all that nice DC biasing and it would not work well. But if you let a capacitor charge up to the difference between the source's operating point (which may be near ground or be far away from it) and the stage's operating point, then the signal just pushes one side of the capacitor around and the other end of the capacitor moves around with it, but at a different DC voltage.